# Analysing Java Files using CKJM tool

Tags: java, class, cmd

I am trying to analyse some files using this CKJM tool I looked at the instructions etc got it to work somehow and there it is another problem it says that my class is not a java file which is not true. How can I get rid of this error and actually scan the java classes?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>java -jar C:\Users\Radostin\Downloads\ckjm_ext.jar C:\Users\
Radostin\Downloads\ServerGame.class
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: C:\Us
ers\Radostin\Downloads\ServerGame.class is not a Java .class file
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:286)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:155)
    at gr.spinellis.ckjm.MetricsFilter.processClass(MetricsFilter.java:97)
    at gr.spinellis.ckjm.MetricsFilter.runMetricsInternal(MetricsFilter.java
    :151)
    at gr.spinellis.ckjm.MetricsFilter.main(MetricsFilter.java:182)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file does not start with `0xCAFEBABE` and is therefore not a Java file.

Take a look at it in a hex editor and see it by yourself.

If you have access to a linux computer or cygwin environment you could try:

```
hexdump -C -n 4 ServerGame.class
```

which should yield

```
00000000  ca fe ba be                                       |....|
00000004
```

Comment: What do you mean not a java file my lecturer told me to run this command with this class file. I am doing exactly as he said lol.

Comment: Your assumption that *it says that my class is not a java file which is not true* is false. It is not a Java file. Take a look as I suggested. Maybe you downloaded some redirect or HTML page or whatever?